# How to safely extract time from date time - Mon Aug 05 2019 14:29:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Tags: javascript

From the input field i am getting this value

```
Mon Aug 05 2019 14:29:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How can safely get this part `14:29:16` which is the time

Comment: did you try anything? We'd like to help you, but you better show what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date("Mon Aug 05 2019 14:29:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = date.getHours() + " : " + date.getMinutes() + " : " + date.getSeconds();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<h1 id="time"></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact solution this would work:

```
function getTime(date) {
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  return [hours, minutes, seconds].join(':');
}
```